# Login using ASIFormDataRequest is not redirecting to the next page

Tags: ios

Am doing login in backend using ASIFormDataRequest in iphone. But the request is not redirecting. Am getting status code 200.

Code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:newUrl];
[newRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[newRequest setPostValue:inUserName forKey:@"username"];
[newRequest setPostValue:inPassword forKey:@"password"];
[newRequest setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[newRequest setDelegate:self];  
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Please help with answers.

Comment: Does the web server respond with a `Location:` header when you POST? If so, `ASIFormDataRequest` *should* automatically redirect to the new location.. but only to do the POST. It doesn't magically know to switch to a GET request when it gets a `200 OK`, you need to construct a separate request for that once the POST comes back.